# Why Trigger SET works only for minus operation, not for sum?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Why if I do an `INSERT` query on the *parking* table it performs the update operation while if I do a `DELETE` query it only print the *"hi"* message but doesn't add the +1?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees

AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON parking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN
UPDATE area_p
SET Capacity = Capacity-1
WHERE NAME_AREA = :NEW.N_AREA;

IF DELETING THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi');
UPDATE area_p
SET Capacity = Capacity+1
WHERE NAME_AREA = :NEW.N_AREA;
END IF;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:OLD` for `DELETE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON parking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    UPDATE area_p
    SET Capacity = Capacity-1
    WHERE NAME_AREA = :NEW.N_AREA;
  END IF;

  IF DELETING THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi');     -- you should avoid print from trigger
    UPDATE area_p
    SET Capacity = Capacity+1
    WHERE NAME_AREA = :OLD.N_AREA;  -- here
  END IF;
END;
/
```

From [About OLD and NEW Pseudorecords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#BCFIGJAE):

> For the row that the trigger is processing:
>
> - For an INSERT trigger, OLD contains no values, and NEW contains the new values.
> - For an UPDATE trigger, OLD contains the old values, and NEW contains the new values.
> - **For a DELETE trigger, OLD contains the old values, and NEW contains no values.**